# Consume webreserv API - <GetProductList>

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, soapui, postman

Im trying in every way I found to consume this API:
http://www.webreserv.com/webservices/http/ServiceManager

Documentation:
https://www.webreserv.com/download/webreserv-booking-system-api-xml.pdf

Keys(temporal for fixing):

**Business ID:** bikeatoursv

**API Key:**  NO longer visible

XML request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request>
<BusinessID>MyBusinessID</BusinessID>
<APIKey>MyAPIKey</APIKey>
<Language>en</Language>
<GetProductList>
</GetProductList>
</Request>
```

XML Response:
none or

```
<Response>
<Error>Error on line 1: Premature end of file.</Error>
</Response>
```

I have tried on `SoapUI`, `postman` and I dont know how to do this.

**SoapUI error:**

> WSDLException (at /Response): faultCode=INVALID_WSDL: Expected element
>   '{http:schemas.xmlsoap. org/ wsdl/}definitions'.

Please give me some help and guidance to try this API on a online tester or know how to consume it in jquery or SoapUI by a real example using the API.

Comment: What did WebServ say when you contacted them?

Comment: they said that I have to talk with a programmer jaja. I guess the people answers me dont know anything about that API except that it exist ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any REST extension for Firefox or Chrome to make a post request and send the XML as a PAYLOAD to the server.  You probably shouldn't post your API Key on here either.

EX. Using `Advanced Rest Client` for Chrome

1. Copy and paste the URL
2. Select Raw for the Payload and copy and paste the XML Request
3. Click Send

[image]

**The Response**

[image]

It doesn't look like the send the cross domain headers so you won't be able to make the call via javascript.

Comment: Woooow thanks ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ, But I read that I won't be able to make the call via javascript :( ? ...how about PHP?

Comment: Yes you can use any server side language to do this or use a regular html form to send the request.  I didn't try soapui earlier but it does work via soapui too.  1. Create new Rest Project 2. Set url to `http://www.webreserv.com/webservices/http/ServiceManager` 3. Select "POST" 4. Copy and paste the XML to the request body 5. click send

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the problem...I dont create it like a REST proyect.